# amplify analytics not able to create log group

Tags: aws-amplify

I have an amplify project where I have enabled analytics. Right now my amplify project's monitoring is on however no log groups were created in cloudwatch, hence I am not able to watch any error or logs in cloudwatch.

Here is my main.ts

```
Analytics.configure({
  // OPTIONAL - Allow recording session events. Default is true.
  autoSessionRecord: true,
});

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
  Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'ERROR';
}
else {
  Amplify.Logger.LOG_LEVEL = 'DEBUG';
}
```

component where I am adding record

```
Analytics.record({
        name: 'test-own',
        immediate: true,
        attributes: {
          user: 'test',
          source: 'tp2Site',
        },
      });
```

is there anything else that's required for this?